# How to create xml in python

Tags: python, xml

Good day.

I am trying to make xml document with python.

Here is part of the code:

```
productChild = root.createElement('product') 
setproduct = ‘Shoe’
productChild.setAttribute(setproduct)
```

And this will output

```
<product>Shoe</product>
```

My question is:
How can make it if setproduct is empty the tag to be `<product/>` and not `<product></product>`

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring), you can pass `short_empty_elements=True` to  the `.write` and `.tostring` methods to have short, self closing tags. it should be automatically on, are you using a different parser or an old version?

Comment: It appears that the OP is using DOM/minidom (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.createElement).

Comment: share the data structure you have and the xml that needs to represent this data structure

Comment: I am creating an xml  structure in odoo to send via api